# Ajustar el desbordamiento de color de un boton en java con swing

Tags: java, java-swing

agregue una clase para modificar el radio de un boton en java pero al momento de usarla provoca un desbordamiento de color que no se acomoda al radio sino al rectangulo normal.
Esta es la clase que implemente para el boton

```
static class RoundedBorder implements Border {

    private int radius;

    RoundedBorder(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(this.radius+1, this.radius+1, this.radius+2, this.radius);
    }

    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return true;
    }

    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        g.drawRoundRect(x, y, width-1, height-1, radius, radius);
    }
}
```

Asi cree el boton

```
JButton Boton_Registrar = new JButton("Entrar");
        Boton_Registrar.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        Boton_Registrar.setBackground(new Color(149,213,178));
        Boton_Registrar.setBounds(210, 470, 150, 40);
        Boton_Registrar.setFont(new Font("montserrat", Font.BOLD, 16));
        Boton_Registrar.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(30));
```

[image: Asi se muestra]

Comment: puedes agregar una captura para entender mejor a que te refieres con desbordamiento?

Comment: Listo, ya anexe una imagen de como sale

Comment: swing ha cambiado mucho, si pudieras poner la version de java que usas tal vez nos seria mas sencillo ayudarte un ejemplo que funcionaba hace tiempo era este: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866252/button-with-round-edges